# Manipulating many JPanels in same Jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I am making an java swing GUI based application, while running this i want to show a Jframe Containing two buttons as shown below :-

[image: Main Home Jframe containing two Buttons]

when clicking on first button that is Name FOrm , it must show a panel containing child components like jlabels etc as shown below :-

[image: Name Form Panel]

Along with a button for going back to the main interface that is Home Frame containing two buttons .

Now after clicking back when we click on Second button thats College Form it must show another Jpanel containing College Info as shown below :-

[image: College panel containing college info]

So here I have explained what i am trying to implement , one single Frame with button for opening respective panels and hiding previous buttons , and then a Button to go back to the Home Jframe.

Need example based on codes. any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either simply call setVisible() on your various JPanels, or you can look into CardLayout.

[How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

If you're confused about how to take an action when the user clicks a button, you need to look into ActionListeners.

[How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Comment: I have already tried that , but in  that case also buttons will appear that i dont want , see am trying to put it in more clear way with an example of windows , when we click on any drive in My Computer it shows the content of that drive and hides My Computers Content with a Back button . Just want the same if its possible..

Comment: If you've tried something, then you should post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing what you've tried. Both approaches I mentioned can be used to achieve the effect you described, so it sounds like you're doing something not quite right. Maybe you're not setting the previous component to invisible before showing the new component?

Comment: Ok suppose i made a panel on main Jframe with Card Layout , can i make button in it??

Comment: am really very sorry , next time i will be careful , and let me test what u suggested if it works i will accept it as answer else let you know .

Comment: @Sushantp606 Actually using CardLayout is a good solution. In your frame you can  have a `BorderLayout` where in `NORTH` you have the title and in the center you have a `JPanel` with `CardLayout` and you swap between each panels +1

Comment: @nachokk Ok i got it , see now i have made a panel with card layout on Jframe with Border Layout, panel contains two buttons , but when i am running this it shows only one single button (a big button occupying whole screen ) can you give me a link or a short example??

Comment: @Sushantp606 Well That is actually about what LayoutManager is using the JPanel, I don't know your code but if all the panels will have FORWARD and PREVIOUS button, i suggest you put that buttons in a container like JPanel and that jpanel in the JFrame with BorderLayout.SOUTH position

Comment: @nachokk Thanks for the suggestion its useful, one more thing , see there is Jpanel1 with card layout , i made another Jpanel Home that consists two button(button1, button2) then added this to main panel by Jpanel_home =new Home();   jPanel1.add(Jpanel_home,"hmpnl"); ,, Now what i want is when i click on Button1 it should fetch another panel thats Student_panel and hide Home panel for that i makde action listener for Button one as CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) student.getLayout(); cl.show(student, "std") . Its not hiding home panel and switching to student panel . how can i show u all the codes

Comment: @Sushantp606 Start to accept this answer with the green mark then make a new question, if it's possible with a [a runnable example, just copy&paste and run](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the problem.